# grub filesystem is fat

Tags: 18.04, grub2

I was tweaking my Ubuntu 18.04 when I accidentally moved the hard drive on which it is installed. Unfortunately, I am now faced with a grub command line interface.
Here is what shows up when I run `ls`:
`(hd0, gpt5) (hd0, gpt4) and others`
After trial and error, I landed on `hd0, gpt1` as others simply returned

> Filesystem is unknown

The issue is running `ls` on `hd0, gpt1` returns

> Filesystem is fat.

How can I best recover my installation or even just boot to Windows?
I can't use `sudo` as it says command is unknown.
Please help a novice out. 
Thanks a lot. (sorry, I'm now typing on my phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one ever encounters this issue, it is actually not an error but simply a message. You can move down directories by using `ls (hdX,gptY)/` which should show up your boot information. However, in  my case moving to `Boot` did not show `grub`.

**Solution**:

I bypassed the command line by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and moving to Boot Load priority using <kbd>F12</kbd> (for my brand) and finally moving on to boot. There was then an auto recovery ran that helped fix the issue finally letting me boot.